# How do I upload a video and get it's URL in Facebook Application

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I am developing a Facebook canvas application which has a feature where the user can upload a video.

I am thinking of following this tutorial : 
[Facebook Video upload documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/493/)

But the problem is that when the user uploads a video I need to get the URL of the video back from Facebook after uploading so that I can store it in my database. And I need to be able to let the users of my Application play it back using an embedded player.

Is this possible ?

If not can you guys suggest some other solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official tutorial will help you understand what and how to hit the right Graph API point to upload a video. But obviously you can't use it as is since you are submitting the form directly to the Facebook end-point and hence you are no longer controlling the frame!

I've written a [tutorial](http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/how-to-upload-a-photo-to-a-users-profile-using-facebook-graph-api/66/) based on a similar code from a Facebook post but uses CURL so that you won't land on the Facebook end-point. It was for uploading images.

Using the same code but with a slight change to make it upload videos instead, your code may look like:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
$app_id = "APP_ID";
$app_secret = "APP_SECRET";
$my_url = "REDIRECT_URI"; // mainly, redirect to this page
$perms_str = "publish_stream";

$code = $_REQUEST["code"];

if(empty($code)) {
    $auth_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id="
    . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
    . "&scope=" . $perms_str;
    echo("<script>top.location.href='" . $auth_url . "'</script>");
}

$token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id="
. $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
. "&client_secret=" . $app_secret
. "&code=" . $code;
$response = file_get_contents($token_url);
$p = null;
parse_str($response, $p);
$access_token = $p['access_token'];
$graph_url= "https://graph-video.facebook.com/me/videos?"
         . "access_token=" .$access_token;
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $params = array();
    if( isset($_POST['title']) ) {
        $params['title'] = trim($_POST['title']);
    }
    if( isset($_POST['description']) ) {
        $params['description'] = trim($_POST['description']);
    }

    $uploaddir = './uploads/'; // Upload folder
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['source']['name']);
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['source']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
        $params['source'] = "@" . realpath($uploadfile);
    }

    // Start the Graph API call
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$graph_url);

    /*
        Next option is only used for
        user from a local (WAMP)
        machine. This should be removed
        when used on a live server!
        refer:https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/issues/7
    */
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $decoded = json_decode($result, true);
    var_dump(curl_error($ch));
    curl_close($ch);
    if(is_array($decoded) && isset($decoded['id'])) {
        /*
            video is uploaded successfully:
            1) show success message
            2) optionally, delete video from our server
        */
        $msg = "Video uploaded successfully: {$decoded['id']}";
    }
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Upload</title>
<style>
label {float: left; width: 100px;}
input[type=text],textarea {width: 210px;}
#msg {border: 1px solid #000; padding: 5px; color: red;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php if( isset($msg) ) { ?>
<p id="msg"><?php echo $msg; ?></p>
<?php } ?>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">
    <p><label for="title">Title</label><input type="text" name="title" value="" /></p>
    <p><label for="description">Description</label><input type="text" name="description" value="" /></p>
    <p><label for="source">Video</label><input type="file" name="source" /></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And here are a couple of notes:

- as mentioned in the tutorial, this is only a demo! you should **not** use the code in  a live app!
- I'm not handling the CURL errors here...but you should! a good start point would be the official PHP-SDK [code](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/src/base_facebook.php#L852)
- I guess you should use a `textarea` for your video description instead of text `input`
- you'll still need the `user_videos` permission to read the video info and get the data you need

Answer (score 2):

Have A look on Facebook documentation!

Here is a link that will help you out too: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/video/

Upload a test video and `print_r` everything that is returned. Somewhere in there should be a video ID. Update the code to grab the video ID and then use the graph API to grab info about the video ID. It will return something like this:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=2031763147233

Then you can simply grab the embed_html section of the video and embed it somewhere.

Sorry I couldn't be of more help, couldn't find any info about what the video api returns but I assume there is an ID. You will have to test it to find out.

Comment: Thank you. But i found @ifaour 's answer more suited for my needs